# Does jdk 1.7 and 1.8 support mule 3.4

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Does mule 3.4 runs with jdk 1.7 & 1.8? Is there any document mentioning about software requirements for running mule 3.4

Answer (score 1):

Actually the question in the title should be the other way around: Does Mule 3.4 supports JDK 1.7 and 1.8?

The answer is that Mule 3.4 does support JDK 1.7 (AKA Java 7) but does not support JDK 1.8 (AKA Java 8). The documentation for 3.4 is archived and it is still available at https://docs.archive.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.4/hardware-and-software-requirements

Note that Mule 3.7.0 is the first release to support Java 8.

Mule 3.4 is a very old release. I would recommend to migrate to a modern, recently released release.